# How can I add a CSS rule to edit.php?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, css

I'm using `add_filter('manage_posts_columns')` in my `plugin.php` to add a column to the Edit Posts listing which is driven by `edit.php`. How can I attach a CSS style to the `edit.php`?

I want to be able to color the background of my column `td`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Creating Admin Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes) article in Codex shows you how to add css styles to admin pages

Comment: Can you update your question to contain the answer rather than linking to it? URLs break and bits rot :(

Answer (score 3):

As helpful as the codex page linked to is, it unfortunately doesn't cover hooking onto a set page or pages, rather the examples given generally hook onto the admin_head, which will load your stylesheet for every admin page (you probably don't want that).

For hooking onto the edit posts screen, the following hook will do that for you..

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-edit.php', 'your-function-callback' );
```

Replace `your-function-callback` with the name of the function you wish to call with the action.